Does DataMember IsRequired work only in XML deserialization?
In my ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project, I have this method:
[HttpPost]
[Route("Search")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SearchResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Search(SearchInput oInputParams)

[DataContract]
public class SearchInput: InputModelBase<SearchParameters>
{
}

[DataContract]
public class SearchParameters: InputModelParametersBase
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [JsonProperty("queryWord")]
    public string QueryWord { get; set; } 

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("queryExt")]
    public string QueryExt { get; set; } = string.Empty;}
}

[DataContract]
public class InputModelParametersBase: IInputModelParameters
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("staticToken")]
    public string StaticToken { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("trace")]
    public bool Trace { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("start")]
    public int Start { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("rows")]
    public int Rows { get; set; } = 20;
}

[DataContract]
public class InputModelBase<T> where T : InputModelParametersBase, new()
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("trace")]
    public bool Trace { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("parameters")]
    public T Parameters { get; set; } = new T();
}

This input json does not generate any errors even if QueryWord is required but missing:
{
    "parameters": { "queryExt": "x:1" },
    "token": "xxx"
}


How about add [Required(ErrorMessage = "QueryWord is required.")]?
